# Which are the right Node & NPM versions for Hyperledger Fabric composer-rest-server?

Tags: node.js, rest, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Does anyone know which are the right node & npm versions to go with this Hyperledger Rest Server?

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/tree/master/packages/composer-rest-server

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yf3pRzZQWnQ

I'm Windows 7 64 Bit user and i get

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

and other warnings while installation process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/stable/installing/installing-prereqs.html):

- Node: 8.9 or higher (note version 9 is not supported)
- npm: v5.x

Note that the documentation says that "**The Hyperledger Composer pre-requisites can be installed on Ubuntu or MacOS**"